# Password strenght of closest keyboard button

Tags: security, passwords, entropy

How can I find the password entropy of a string composed pressing the closest buttons on the keyboard?

I would like to define with an algoritm in witch strings like:

```
querty
```

or

```
asdfghjk
```

are checked like bad passwords.

There is a way to calculate that without dictionaries?

Comment: Do you mean `qwerty`, or do you have some keyboard arrangement I'm not familiar with?

Comment: Interesting question. It would require information of the phyiscal location of the characters on the keyboard. Did you already search if such information is available?

Comment: @frank I think that it's not possible by javascript or some other hack to get the current keyboard layout. The most used keyboard layout in the world are less than 10. 
For example you can cross the user's ip (to obtain the country in which is located) and the most used keyboard in that country. I post you a link: http://matadornetwork.com/abroad/the-ultimate-guide-to-computer-keyboards-around-the-world/
Obviously if the user is connected with a VPN the calculated password/passphrase strenght could be wrong. I thought to do a control without including special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by myself.

Actually I'm checking only "qwerty" keyboards.

The `getMaxPathLength` function gives the maximum path of adjacent keys searching in all the directions.

```
<?php
/*
 *  Find the max path in a qwerty keyboard giving an input string
    Copyright (C) 2013  Danilo Rossini <rossinidan@gmail.com>

    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.


    USAGE: 

    // Examples
    $array = array("qwertyui");  //get 8 as result
    $array = array("quedc");     //get 5 as result
    $array = array("qaz");       //get 3 as result
    $array = array("zxcdfvppp"); //get 6 as result

    $fp = new Path_length("qwertyu");
    echo $fp->getMaxPathLength();
 */
class Path_length{

     private $maxPathLength = 1;

     /* 
     * Keyboard layout: QUERTY
     */
     private $matrix = array( 
        array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"),
        array("q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p"),
        array("a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l"),
        array("z","x","c","v","b","n","m"),
     );

     private $colSize = 10;
     private $rowSize = 4;

     private $arrayInput = array();
     private $arraySize = null;



     public function __construct($inputString) {

         if(!isset($inputString)) die("NULL input array!");

         $this->splitStringInArray($inputString);
         $this->cycleMatrix();
     }


     public function getMaxPathLength(){
         return $this->maxPathLength;
     }

     /**
      * Split each element of the string into an array and store it, with his length
      * in global variables
      * @param type $string
      */
     private function splitStringInArray($string){

        $length   = strlen($string);
        $tmpArray = array();

        for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
            $tmpArray[$i] = $string[$i];
        }

        $this->arraySize  = $length;
        $this->arrayInput = $tmpArray;
     }

     /**
      * Iterate each element of the matrix, calling the function $this->findPath
      */
     private function cycleMatrix(){

         for($i=0;$i<$this->colSize;$i++){
             for($j=0;$j<$this->rowSize;$j++){

                 if(isset($this->matrix[$j][$i]) && $this->arrayInput[0]==$this->matrix[$j][$i]){
                     $this->findPath($j, $i, $this->maxPathLength, 1);
                 }

             }
         }

     }

     /**
      * Recursive function that search if the closest element in the matrix (up, down, left, right)
      * is contained in the input array at the cursor pointer.
      * It save into $this->maxPathLength the maximum length path found.
      * 
      * @param int $a   -> x position on the matrix
      * @param int $b   -> y position on the matrix
      * @param int $max -> max path lenght found until now by the recursive call
      * @param int $c   -> array cursor on the input array
      * @return int
      */
     private function findPath($a, $b, $max, $c){

        $this->maxPathLength = max(array($this->maxPathLength, $max));

        if($a>=($this->rowSize-1) && $b>=($this->colSize-1)) {
            return 1;
        }

        if($c===$this->arraySize) {
            return 1;
        }

        /* Search next right key */
        if(isset($this->matrix[$a+1][$b]) && 
           $this->matrix[$a+1][$b]===$this->arrayInput[$c] && 
           $this->findPath($a+1, $b, $max+1, $c+1)){
          return 1;  
        }

        /* Search next bottom key */
        if(isset($this->matrix[$a][$b+1]) &&
           $this->matrix[$a][$b+1]===$this->arrayInput[$c] &&
           $this->findPath($a, $b+1, $max+1, $c+1)){
            return 1;
        }

        /* Search next left key */
        if(isset($this->matrix[$a-1][$b]) && 
           $this->matrix[$a-1][$b]===$this->arrayInput[$c] && 
           $this->findPath($a-1, $b, $max+1, $c+1)){
          return 1;  
        }

        /* Search next up key */
        if(isset($this->matrix[$a][$b-1]) && 
           $this->matrix[$a][$b-1]===$this->arrayInput[$c] && 
           $this->findPath($a, $b-1, $max+1, $c+1)){
          return 1;  
        }

        return 0;
    }
 }
```

**Edit**

New version of the previous code with detection of shifted keys.

```
<?php
/*
 *  Find the max path in a qwerty keyboard giving an input string
    Copyright (C) 2013  Danilo Rossini <rossinidan@gmail.com>

    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.


    USAGE: 

    // Examples
    $string = "qwertyui";  //get 8 as result
    $string = "qwedc";     //get 5 as result

    $fp = new Path_length("qwertyu");
    echo $fp->getMaxPathLength();
 */

class Path_length{

     private $maxPathLength = 1;

     /* 
     * Keyboard layout: QUERTY
     */
     private $keyLower = array(
        array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"),
        array("q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p"),
        array("a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l"),
        array("z","x","c","v","b","n","m"),  
     );

     private $keyUpper = array(
        array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"),
        array("Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P"),
        array("A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L"),
        array("Z","X","C","V","B","N","M"),
     );

     private $matrix = array();

     private $colSize = 10;
     private $rowSize = 4;

     private $arrayInput = array();
     private $arraySize = null;



     public function __construct($inputString) {

         if(!isset($inputString) || !is_string($inputString)) die("Invalid input string!");

         $this->initKeyboard();
         $this->splitStringInArray($inputString);
         $this->cycleMatrix();
     }

     private function initKeyboard(){
         $this->matrix[0] = $this->keyLower;
         $this->matrix[1] = $this->keyUpper;
     }

     public function getMaxPathLength(){
         return $this->maxPathLength;
     }

     /**
      * Split each element of the string into an array and store it, with his length
      * in global variables
      * @param type $string
      */
     private function splitStringInArray($string){

        $length   = strlen($string);
        $tmpArray = array();

        for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
            $tmpArray[$i] = $string[$i];
        }

        $this->arraySize  = $length;
        $this->arrayInput = $tmpArray;
     }

     private function isUpper($chr){
         return ctype_upper($chr) ? 1 : 0;
     }

     /**
      * Iterate each element of the matrix, calling the function $this->findPath
      */
     private function cycleMatrix(){


         for($i=0;$i<$this->colSize;$i++){
             for($j=0;$j<$this->rowSize;$j++){


                 for($c=0; $c<$this->arraySize; $c++) {
                    $isUp = $this->isUpper($this->arrayInput[$c]);

                    if( isset($this->matrix[$isUp][$j][$i]) && 
                        $this->arrayInput[$c]===$this->matrix[$isUp][$j][$i]){
                           $this->findPath($j, $i, 1, $c+1, $isUp);
                    }
                 }

             }
         }

     }

     /**
      * Recursive function that search if the closest element in the matrix (up, down, left, right)
      * is contained in the input array at the cursor pointer.
      * It save into $this->maxPathLength the maximum length path found.
      * 
      * @param int $a   -> x position on the matrix
      * @param int $b   -> y position on the matrix
      * @param int $max -> max path lenght found until now by the recursive call
      * @param int $c   -> array cursor on the input array
      * @return int
      */
     private function findPath($a, $b, $max, $c, $isUp){

        $this->maxPathLength = max(array($this->maxPathLength, $max));

        if($a>=($this->rowSize-1) && $b>=($this->colSize-1)) {
            return 1;
        }

        if($c===$this->arraySize) {
            return 1;
        }

        /* Search next right key */
        if(isset($this->matrix[$isUp][$a+1][$b]) && 
           $this->matrix[$isUp][$a+1][$b]===$this->arrayInput[$c] && 
           $this->findPath($a+1, $b, $max+1, $c+1, $isUp)){
          return 1;  
        }

        /* Search next bottom key */
        if(isset($this->matrix[$isUp][$a][$b+1]) &&
           $this->matrix[$isUp][$a][$b+1]===$this->arrayInput[$c] &&
           $this->findPath($a, $b+1, $max+1, $c+1, $isUp)){
            return 1;
        }

        /* Search next left key */
        if(isset($this->matrix[$isUp][$a-1][$b]) && 
           $this->matrix[$isUp][$a-1][$b]===$this->arrayInput[$c] && 
           $this->findPath($a-1, $b, $max+1, $c+1, $isUp)){
          return 1;  
        }

        /* Search next up key */
        if(isset($this->matrix[$isUp][$a][$b-1]) && 
           $this->matrix[$isUp][$a][$b-1]===$this->arrayInput[$c] && 
           $this->findPath($a, $b-1, $max+1, $c+1, $isUp)){
          return 1;  
        }

        return 0;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Cool solution. You might want to expand it to the shifted versions of all keys, to expand the number of passwords it can be applied to.

Comment: You might want to verify that the license you specify for your code is in line with StackOverflow (Creative Commons) policies. See for example this meta discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow and the terms of use here: http://stackexchange.com/legal

Comment: For future reference, if you decide to support different keyboard layouts, you can see the different ones (for windows) here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964651.aspx

Comment: @frank, thank you so much for the suggestions and to correct my English mistakes. =) ..I have not yet had the opportunity to read the StackOverflow policies. I will do that for sure.